# Android Studio Download Error

Tags: android, java, android-studio, download

Okay, I know this is a common problem with downloading Android Studio in Windows, but after I downloaded and opened Android Studio I got the error message: "No JVM installation found.  Please intall a 64-bit JDK.  If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables."...
So I did this, or at least I think I did.  I typed Environment Variables into the Start Task Manager and opened it up.  Then I added the JAVA_HOME variable with the path, C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21...all the examples I see have Program Files, instead of Program Files (x86)...I know the difference, just wanted to tell you everything.  Anyway, after I did that, it still showed the error and didn't work.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: the error message requested a 64 bit jvm but it appears that you installed a 32 bit one. download a 64 bit jvm and install that instead.